# Change repo checkout agent for reading Jenkinsfile in pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, git-checkout

I have a git repo that contains multiple Jenkinsfiles. These Jenkinsfiles contain various `agent` directive to control which node they are running on.

However, the first step of the job, which is reading the Jenkinsfile itself, is defined on the Jenkins website (since it cannot be contained in the Jenkinsfile itself). Namely, I use the "Pipeline script from SCM" section, with the repo and credentials correctly set up.

The problem is that this first checkout step is not always being executed on the master node. It is sometimes - seemingly randomly - performed on another agent which has no SSH access to the repo (public key). Is there any way I can control on which node this checkout is executed?

When the checkout is performed correctly on the master node, the Jenkinsfile redirects it to another node which performs the rest of the job without any issues.

This is what it looks like:

- `agent1` runs a (lightweight) checkout
- `agent1` reads the Jenkinsfile
- The Jenkinsfile contains `agent { label 'agent2' }`
- The rest of the Jenkinsfile is executed on `agent2`

I would like to force `agent1` to be a certain agent (the master node, specifically). Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Until you read `Jenkinsfile` you cannot know what agent it specifies. Typically the master will perform SCM checkout and hand the resulting repo to the agent. Alternatively, the master can perform a lightweight checkout of just the Jenkinsfile, then the Jenkinsfile can perform a manual `checkout scm` step. Both approaches have limitations. Without knowing the "several issues" you're facing it's hard to recommend an approach.

Comment: The problem is that the SCM checkout is not always happening on the same agent. When it runs on the master, everything is fine, but it sometimes runs on another agent, which does not have SSH access to the repo and therefore fails to clone it (this is the main issue). I cannot really give SSH access to this second agent, which is why I'm trying to get the checkout to run on the master.

Comment: Ah. Internally we handle this by marking all agents but the master as "Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node." There may be a better solution, though.